# Sharing content to Facebook within Android App using Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook

In Android app, I am implementing a feature "Share to Facebook". I am using native framework provided by Facebook. 
My application will be able to post successfully to Facebook if "Facebook" app is not installed on the phone/tab. But if "Facebook" app is installed, it's not posting to Facebook.
Here's my code:

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Title Here")
                .setContentDescription("Description Here")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.someurl.com/mypage.html"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://someurl.com/image.png"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

With Facebook app installed, when above code is executed, its showing empty screen where user can enter some comment and post it. Its not posting actual "Title Here" or "Description Here" or my content url or image url.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082096/how-to-cutomize-twitter-and-facebook-login-buttons-on-android-studio

Comment: @Aakash, I was referring to posting the content and not about the decoration of the buttons.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the issue? moreover, have you tried using one of the bundled sample projects with the latest SDK? if that works then this is most likely an issue from your implementaiton